# Is the sscanf function in the Linux kernel susceptible to buffer overflow attacks?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, buffer-overflow

From what I understand, a typical buffer overflow attack occurs when an attack overflows a buffer of memory on the stack, thus allowing the attacker to inject malicious code and rewrite the return address on the stack to point to that code.

This is a common concern when using functions (such as `sscanf`) that blindly copy data from one area to another, checking one for a termination byte:

```c
char str[8];                               /* holds up to 8 bytes of data */
char *buf = "lots and lots of foobars";    /* way more than 8 bytes of data */
sscanf(buf, "%s", str);                    /* buffer overflow occurs here! */
```

I noticed some `sysfs_ops` `store` functions in the Linux kernel are implemented with the Linux kernel's version of the `sscanf` function:

```c
static char str[8];    /* global string */
static ssize_t my_store(struct device *dev,
                        struct device_attribute *attr,
                        const char *buf, size_t size)
{
        sscanf(buf, "%s", str);    /* buf holds more than 8 bytes! */
        return size;
}
```

Suppose this `store` callback function is set to a writable `sysfs` attribute. Would a malicious user be able to intentionally overflow the buffer via a `write` call?

Normally, I would expect guards against buffer overflow attacks -- such as limiting the number of bytes read -- but I see none in a good number of functions (for example in [drivers/scsi/scsi_sysfs.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/scsi/scsi_sysfs.c?v=3.2#L260)).

Does the implementation of the Linux kernel version of `sscanf` protect against buffer overflow attacks; or is there another reason -- perhaps buffer overflow attacks are impossible given how the Linux kernel works under the hood?

Comment: Software security means understanding what you are protecting and who you are protecting it from. What is your worry? That a loadable kernel module may cause a buffer overflow elsewhere in the kernel? A rogue device? `sscanf()` is not insecure in itself, it is only insecure if the attacker can pass it the wrong arguments.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Forgive me, I'm still new to `sysfs`. If an attribute is writable, couldn't a malicious user intentionally overflow the buffer with a `write` call to the attribute file?

Comment: I don't know sysfs either, I just think your question is a better question with this comment you just wrote.

Comment: +1 : Much nicer than portability questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Linux [`sscanf()`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/lib/vsprintf.c) is vulnerable to buffer overflows; inspection of the source shows this.  You can use [width specifiers](http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/String-overflows-with-scanf.html) to limit the amount a `%s` is allowed to write.   At some point your `str` must have had `copy_from_user()` run on it as well.  It is possible the *user space* to pass some garbage pointer to the kernel.

In the version of Linux you cited, the [scsi_sysfs.c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/scsi/scsi_sysfs.c) does have a buffer overflow.  The latest version does not.  The [committed fix](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/drivers/scsi/scsi_sysfs.c?id=072f19b4bea31cdd482d79f805413f2f9ac9e233) should fix the issue you see.

Comment: How would the user space pass an invalid pointer to the kernel?

Comment: Nevermind, I realized that the character buffer pointer is passed through a system call such as `read` or `write` -- thus the user could theoretically pass an invalid pointer, such as one pointing to a kernel space address.

Comment: Why is it then that the function pointers in the [`sysfs_ops` structure](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/sysfs.h?v=3.9#L124) don't apply `__user` macro to the buffer pointer? For example, why is it not: `ssize_t (*show)(struct kobject *, struct attribute *,char __user *);`

Comment: `__user` is defined in [compiler.h](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/compiler.h).  You can see it does nothing unless **__CHECKER__** is defined.  The `make C=1` will use the `__user` annotations.  See [Sparse wiki](https://sparse.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page).  So functionally, it does nothing for compiled code.  It just means they will not be checked by the *checker*, if you are correct and they do come from user space. Sorry, I didn't check ;-)

Comment: I need to go back on what I said earlier; I don't think the buffer for the `sysfs_ops` functions are located in userspace. When I try using `copy_to_user`/`copy_from_user` with the buffer, I get a `bad address` error. Perhaps `sysfs` is doing some magic that allocates a kernelspace buffer for the data.

Comment: Sorry, I was a little confusing.  I don't know that the sysfs is using user space buffers or not.  I just meant when using `sscanf()` in general.  For instance from an `ioctl()` or something (in the spirit of [Pascal's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/139746/pascal-cuoq) comment); **sysfs** is a *pseudo* file system and data may already be transferred from *user space* by the time it gets to the callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

`sscanf`, when well called, will not cause buffer overflow, especially in sysfs  `xxx_store()` function. (There are a lot `sscanf` in sysfs `XXX_store()` examples), because Linux kernel add a `'\0'` (zero-terminated) byte after the string (`buf[len] = 0;`) for your `XXX_store()` function.

Long answer:

Normally, sysfs are defined to have a strict formatted data.   Since you expect 8 bytes at most, it's reasonable to limit the size you get like this:

```
static char str[8];    /* global string */
static ssize_t my_store(struct device *dev,
                        struct device_attribute *attr,
                        const char *buf, size_t size)
{
        if (size > 8) {
                printk("Error: Input size > 8: too large\n");
                return -EINVAL;
        }
        sscanf(buf, "%s", str);    /* buf holds more than 8 bytes! */
        return size;
}
```

(Note: use 9 rather than 8, if you expect a 8-bytes string plus '\n')

(Note that you do reject some inputs such as those with many leading white spaces.  However, who would send a string with many leading white spaces? Those who want to break your code, right?  If they don't follow your spec, just reject them.)

Note that Linux kernel purposely inserts a `'\0'` at offset `len` (i.e. `buf[len] = 0;`) when the user write `len` bytes to sysfs purposely for safe `sscanf`, as said in a comment in kernel 2.6: `fs/sysfs/file.c`:

```
static int 
fill_write_buffer(struct sysfs_buffer * buffer, const char __user * buf, size_t count)
{
    int error;

    if (!buffer->page)
        buffer->page = (char *)get_zeroed_page(GFP_KERNEL);
    if (!buffer->page)
        return -ENOMEM;

    if (count >= PAGE_SIZE)
        count = PAGE_SIZE - 1;
    error = copy_from_user(buffer->page,buf,count);
    buffer->needs_read_fill = 1;
    /* if buf is assumed to contain a string, terminate it by \0,
       so e.g. sscanf() can scan the string easily */
    buffer->page[count] = 0;
    return error ? -EFAULT : count;
}
...
static ssize_t
sysfs_write_file(struct file *file, const char __user *buf, size_t count, loff_t *ppos)
{
    struct sysfs_buffer * buffer = file->private_data;
    ssize_t len;

    mutex_lock(&buffer->mutex);
    len = fill_write_buffer(buffer, buf, count);
    if (len > 0)
        len = flush_write_buffer(file->f_path.dentry, buffer, len);
    if (len > 0)
        *ppos += len;
    mutex_unlock(&buffer->mutex);
    return len;
}
```

Higher kernel version keeps the same logic (though already completely rewritten).